# Adding a file to SQL table - never saves

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to update a column of datatype image with a local file

```
Update tblabc
set DOCBLOB =(Select * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\TEMP\abc.doc', SINGLE_BLOB) AS img)
where ID= 62
GO
```

The query appears to execute correctly (no error) but the column remains as NULL. I run the query in MSMS and then immediately check the table. I originally was trying to update the blob column using C# but get the same result — I get no error but never see the update.

I have successfully updated a text column so assume permissions are OK.

```
(Select * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\TEMP\abc.doc', SINGLE_BLOB) AS img)
```

returns a column Bulkcolumn successfully populated

Comment: Do you check the value immediately after the UPDATE, or do you do it in another database session?  If it is checked in a new session, the problem might be that you've not committed the change.  Given the file name, it is reasonable to guess that you're using a version of MS SQL Server.  If that's correct, it would also be a good idea to tag the question with one of the MS SQL Server tags; if it's not correct, it would be a good idea to identify which DBMS you _are_ using instead.  (Or, in other words, always identify the DBMS you're using as well as the [tag:sql] when asking SQL questions.)

Comment: In general, when people ask in comments for clarifications, it is best to update the question with the extra information.  I've done that for you this time — please remember for the future.

Comment: Can I suggest running just: `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\TEMP\abc.doc', SINGLE_BLOB) AS img` (the body of the sub-select) and check that it returns you a non-NULL value.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas.  I don't use SQL Server so I have no domain expertise there that can help.

Comment: Silly question, but does the tblabc table actually have a row in it that has an ID of 62?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd recommend to **dump** the `image` datatype and use `varbinary(max)` instead - `image` has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 ....

Secondly, I'd slightly rewrite your `UPDATE` statement to be this:

```
UPDATE TblFiles
SET DOCBLOB = img.BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\TEMP\abc.doc', SINGLE_BLOB) AS img
WHERE ID = 62
```

In my case, this works just fine - the binary column gets updated with the contents of the file specified in the `OPENROWSET` call

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was a Trigger (code that executes) on the table I was trying to update.
So my update was being reversed each time.

Once I disabled the trigger my original query worked